# which is the proper syntax for this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am following along in jquery the missing manual and an example says to write it out like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
```

but when I continue reading it it says your code should look like this:

```
 $(function() {
        $('body').hide().fadeIn(1000);
   });
```

it drove me crazy because I'm a beginner, they both seem to work but I want to know which is proper

Comment: The second one does absolutely nothing. Are you sure you didn't forget `()` somewhere?

Comment: I had to forgot the '$, sign before the function. but it does run

Comment: and why would the book say to different things. its called java script and query the missing manual page 34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are identical. The only thing that would make the second one better is that is is less code to type. It is only a shorthand version of the document ready function.

jQuery has a few of these "shortcuts". Another example is the click handler. It can be written in two ways:

```
$( element ).click( function(){ ... } );

$( element ).on( "click", function(){ ... } );
```

Going back to the document ready statement, the jQuery documentation has this to say about the two different versions:

> Experienced developers sometimes use shorthand for `$( document ).ready()`. If you are writing code that people who aren't experienced with jQuery may see, it's best to use the long form.

Comment: so '$(document).ready' doesn't need to be there. So as long as the dollar sign is there I can remove '$(document).ready'

Comment: You shouldn't look at it like a string... It a function call - they *are* different but have the same behavior. But yes - you are correct.